# C# DecimalSeparator

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

В книгах`/`манулах про С# не нашел, как обозначать разделители. Например, в С++ разделителем дробных чисел выступал DecimalSeparator, а для разделения составляющих времени вроде как используется TimeSeparator. Ищу подобное для С Шарпа.

---

З.Ы.: Коды символов и их представления в скобках не канают, ибо тогда программа будет зависима от конфигураций ПК.

Comment: Какие разделители? Разделители чего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для манипуляции с разными форматами даты и времени используй свойства из пространства System.Globalization :

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.TimeSeparator
DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator
```

Нельзя назначить обоим полям одинаковые значения. И с числами:

```
NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator
NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator
```

Так же нельзя назначать одинаковые значения этим двум полям.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только на "NumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator" почему то ругается, "NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator" пашет.